# Java get a reference to file from src folder

Tags: java, junit, java-io

I would like to replace the original resource file inside a unit test. Exactly I want to regenerate some expected test results using a unit test.

I have issue how I can load the file outside of my target folder. I have the following structure (simplify version):

- src

  - main
  - test

    - resources

      - expected

        - file.json
- target

  - test-classes

    - expected

      - file.json

I want to access and replace the 'src/test/resources/expected/file.json' file from the above structure.

The following line access the file from the target folder:

```
    ReplaceDocumentTest.class.getResource("/expected/file.json");
```

I tried to go upper with the relative path but it didn't work.

```
    ReplaceDocumentTest.class.getResource("/../../src/test/resources/expected/file.json");
```

How can I obtain a reference to the file.json inside the 'src' folder?

Comment: Try:

    InputStream is = ReplaceDocumentTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/expected/file.json");

But better way to use it is:
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("/expected/file.json");

Comment: @Tryingmybest Your suggestion gets the reference to the file inside the target folder. I need the file reference from src folder. I need this reference because I would like to override the file.

Comment: not sure what is meant by "override the file", but `ClassLoader` (or `getResource`) will only be able to get files that are on the CLASSPATH - maybe you must use `File` or `Path` (and usually there is something wrong if needing to access files from the source folder)

Comment: @user16320675 I want to regenerate the expected files that are used in other unit tests. I want to regenerate these expected file without any manual interaction: like copy manually the new version of expected files to the resources folder.

Comment: You can’t.  A compiled application does not have a source directory.  Even if you get it to work on your computer, it will not work anywhere else, because most people won’t have access to the source.  The best you can do is look for a file with the same name in a known location, like the current user’s home directory, and if that exists, use it instead of the bundled resource.

Comment: But if it’s just for the purposes of running tests, usually the source code is available in that case. You’ll just need to use a file system path, as @user16320675 said above.